# How to set brightness effects on specific columns on the stacked column/bar chart when using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, hover, bar-chart

I am trying to give a brightness effect on specific columns on stacked bar chart using Highcharts.

I want to develop the effect as the right side "SOLUTION" of below picture.

[image]

Now when hovering over a series or a column, i.e. Apples-John, it can be seen that the entire bar's brightness changes

The code: HTML is

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

The code: JavaScript is

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent'
        },
        series: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        brightness: -0.3
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

What I want to do is to give brightness to four columns of John's when hovering any of John's columns: all of the skyblue columns; if I hover one of the Jane's columns, it is needed to change brightness of all Jane's columns: five black columns in a Jane group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some css you can achieve it , first add className in the series data like this(you can declare the name as you like right now I'm used the name as the className)

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    className:'John'
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
    className:'Jane'
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
    className:'Joe'
}]
```

Once you add the className , after rendering you will find the name in the Highcharts div, what you need to do  is add the color which you wants to show on the hove use **fill** for that.

Example:

```
#container .highcharts-container .highcharts-series-group .John:hover rect{
   fill: rgb(230, 44, 118);
}
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/2fruqw7j/12/

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to set opacity on **.highcharts-column-series rect** element:

```
.highcharts-column-series:hover rect {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Also, you might want to disable default brightness:

```
series: {
  states: {
    hover: {
      brightness: 0
    }
  }
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2m8t6knh

Comment: Simple & Perfect